# Upload multiple files: max_file_uploads is not working

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter

I set `max_file_uploads` to value `200` in `php.ini`, restarted Apache and make an upload process with 30 input files. Below is my code:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="subavatar[]" />
    <input type="file" name="subavatar[]" />
    <input type="file" name="subavatar[]" />
    ... // Total quantity is 30
</form>
```

In my controller, I use `var_dump` to detect upload data:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_FILES['subavatar']['error']);
echo '</pre>';
die;
```

And there are the results:

```
[error] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
        [1] => 4
        [2] => 4
        [3] => 4
        [4] => 4
        [5] => 4
        [6] => 4
        [7] => 4
        [8] => 0
        [9] => 4
        [10] => 4
        [11] => 4
        [12] => 4
        [13] => 4
        [14] => 4
        [15] => 4
        [16] => 4
        [17] => 4
        [18] => 4
        [19] => 4
    )
```

Only 20 files received, with 2 files uploaded to temp directory.

What are my wrong? How to configuration for getting more files?
A cup of beer for any help :) 
Sorry for my bad English!

### FULL CODE

File `controllers/Upload.php`

```
class Upload extends CI_Controller {
    public function index() {
        if ($this->input->post()) {
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($_FILES['subavatar']['error']);
            echo '</pre>';
            die;
        }
        $this->load->view('upload/index');
    }
}
```

File `views/upload/index.php`

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="subavatar[]" />
    <input type="file" name="subavatar[]" />
    <input type="file" name="subavatar[]" />
    <input type="file" name="subavatar[]" />
    <input type="file" name="subavatar[]" />
    <input type="file" name="subavatar[]" />
    <input type="file" name="subavatar[]" />
    <input type="file" name="subavatar[]" />
    <input type="file" name="subavatar[]" />
    <input type="file" name="subavatar[]" />
    <input type="file" name="subavatar[]" />
    <input type="file" name="subavatar[]" />
    <input type="file" name="subavatar[]" />
    <input type="file" name="subavatar[]" />
    <input type="file" name="subavatar[]" />
    <input type="file" name="subavatar[]" />
    <input type="file" name="subavatar[]" />
    <input type="file" name="subavatar[]" />
    <input type="file" name="subavatar[]" />
    <input type="file" name="subavatar[]" />
    <input type="file" name="subavatar[]" />
    <input type="file" name="subavatar[]" />
    <input type="file" name="subavatar[]" />
    <input type="file" name="subavatar[]" />
    <input type="file" name="subavatar[]" />
    <input type="file" name="subavatar[]" />
    <input type="file" name="subavatar[]" />
    <input type="file" name="subavatar[]" />
    <input type="file" name="subavatar[]" />
    <input type="file" name="subavatar[]" />
</form>
```

Comment: show your upload code

Comment: I just only printed `$_FILES`, no any code upload. Above is all my script :)

Comment: which PHP version you are using ?

Comment: You can try to add this two lines *max_file_uploads = 100    
suhosin.upload.max_uploads=100* in php.ini , maybe its work.

Comment: I just have put all my script. I use CodeIgniter 2

Comment: Thanks for your help, all Bros. It seems the limit upload of `suhosin.upload.max_uploads`. I increased the value to `100` and now its working normally. Thanks again so much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the server was limiting it to 20. you can try with below things,
in php.ini just find "max_file_uploads" and change its value to 100

add below line under the max_file_uploads

***suhosin.upload.max_uploads=100***

for example:

```
max_file_uploads = 100    
suhosin.upload.max_uploads=100
```

not much sure as it works and exact solution ,but you can try with this.

Answer (score 0):

Set max_file_uploads on php.ini to the number of files you need.

If it is not working:

1. Be sure you are editing the correct php.ini
2. You have to restart your server
3. Try to add suhosin.upload.max_uploads under max_file_uploads with same number of files needed.